# Не работает hibernate на heroku(tomcat)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, amazon-web-services

Database стоит на aws rds. При работе на моем ноутбуке приложение нормально общается с базой, только викину на хостинг(*.war, servlet 3.0, hibernate 5.x) heroku or aws Elastic Beanstalk. Сразу получаю стактрейс что клас(который отдает сесию) не инициализуется. С чем ето связано? Как настроить верно?

HibernateUtil, там гетер для получения сесии

```
static {
       try {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = 
           new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metaData = 
            new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
       } catch (Throwable th) {
        System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
      }
    }
```

StackTrase

```
21-Apr-2018 18:49:59.093 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [apiServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.hemagglutinin.gateway.dao.HibernateUtil
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.dao.ClientDAO.getSession(ClientDAO.java:36)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.dao.ClientDAO.getByUser(ClientDAO.java:26)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.service.ValidateService.userValidate(ValidateService.java:43)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.service.ValidateService.validateCustomerReq(ValidateService.java:22)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.servlets.ApiServlet.doGet(ApiServlet.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки к вопросу.

Comment: Покажите трейс ошибки и код

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Добавил

Comment: @GenCloud Добавил, код ето просто утилитный класс для получения сесии, коректно работает локально. Увы кода нету под рукой

Comment: У вас в нём нет блока статической инициализации случаем? Лучше всего приложите код класса `HibernateUtil`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил, есть блок статики, там еще гетер для получения сессии из фабрики.

Comment: Ошибка `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXX` обычно означает, что в блоке инициализации возникло исключение.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хм, возможно при деплое, файл xml не видит. Вы моментом не занимаетесь деплоем heroku or aws?

Comment: Не обязательно, там много чего вылезти может. Я бы убрал try-catch и посмотрел, что конкретно выбросит инициализация.

Comment: Я имел дела с AWS и с Heroku, но вместе их применять пока не приходилось.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я также делал деплой на aws, там та же проблема

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой код работает без исключений

```
static {
    try {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = 
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metaData = 
            new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
    }
}
```